# Como inibir o botão "voltar" em uma aplicação React Native usando react-navigation-fluid-transitions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-fluid-transitions

Estou criando uma aplicação mobile que utiliza como base o [`react-native`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/). Para fazer a transição entre as telas e para ter uma melhor experiência para o usuário, estou usando as bibliotecas [`react-navigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/) e [`react-navigation-fluid-transitions`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-fluid-transitions).

Minha aplicação tem um **SplashScreen** personalizado que tem uma série de animações e, após finalizarem o usuário é direcionado para a **LoginScreen** ou a **WorkspaceScreen**.

> A tela de **SplashScreen** aproveita do tempo das animações para verificar se há algum usuário na persistência, se houver manda para a **WorkspaceScreen** caso contrário manda para a **LoginScreen**.

Meu componente que gerencia as transições das rotas está assim:

**FluidNavigator** (`./navigation/FluidNavigator/index.js`)

```js
import React from 'react'
import { FluidNavigator } from 'react-navigation-fluid-transitions'

import SplashScreen from '../../screens/SplashScreen'
import LoginScreen from '../../screens/LoginScreen'
import WorkspaceScreenfrom '../../screens/WorkspaceScreen'
// ... outras screen's aqui

export default Navigator = FluidNavigator({
  SplashScreen: { screen: SplashScreen },
  LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen, },
  WorkspaceScreen: { screen: WorkspaceScreen},
  // ... outras rotas aqui
});
```

Meu problema é que, caso o usuário esteja na **LoginScreen** ou na **WorkspaceScreen** e pressione o botão de voltar o mesmo está voltando para **SplashScreen**.

O que preciso fazer para inibir que o usuário retorne à tela de **SplashScreen** nessas situações?

Answer (score 1):

Para inibir o botão "voltar" em uma aplicação React Native usando react-navigation-fluid-transitions, você precisará usar a função "goBack" para desabilitar o botão. Em seu arquivo de navegação, basta incluir a seguinte linha de código antes de renderizar a tela:

```
this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depois de 4 horas de procuras e então postar essa pergunta, eu encontrei esse vídeo que resolve meu problema:

- [React-Native tutorial # 36 disable back button in navigation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWfAVzJp9ao)

A solução é dentro das minhas screen's que não forem ter um retorno para a tela anterior, eu desabilitar o botão. Sendo assim as screen's ficariam assim:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, BackHandler } from 'react-native'

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount = () => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => true);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>LoginScreen</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default LoginScreen
```

Comment: tem uma forma mais elegante de fazer isso usando o [SwitchNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html) do `react-navigation`